# PHP if condition based on date not working

Tags: php, mysql

I want to execute a `if` statement where I want if given `{date}` is less or equal than `today` then `{due_amount}= {paidbystudent}` else `{due_amount}= '0'`

Here is my code:

```
if ({date} <= Today()) {
    {due_amount}={paidbystudent};
}  else {
    {due_amount}='0';
}
```

But its not working. Please help me how to do this.

I have also tried this code but its not working properly this is checking only date and ignoring month and year

```
$todays_date=date("d/m/Y", strtotime("today"));
$date=date("d/m/Y", strtotime({date}));

if ($date <= $todays_date) {
    {due_amount}={paidbystudent};
}  else {
    {due_amount}='0';
}
```

Comment: Start using DateTime class instead of strtotime() using createFromFormat()

Comment: Pls show me a sample so that i can use that. thanx

Comment: Get rid of `date()`. compare the result of `strtotime`. You are telling PHP to compare two strings, PHP doesn't know that they represent dates.

Comment: Use the format `YYYY-MM-DD` (`Y-m-d`) if you want to compare as strings, though you should just use `new DateTime() <= new DateTime($date)`.

Comment: How about you [read the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and try it yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
$date = '2014-05-22'; // fetch from db, user input etc   

if (strtotime($date) <= time()) {
    echo 'paid by student';
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/uuOMiV)

EDIT: As pointed out by deceze, a better way to approach this would be to compare the UNIX timestamp values instead of a date format.

Comment: Anti-demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/dJdyhJ - Comparing the least significant parts first leads to wrong result.

Comment: Aha..wasn't aware of that. So I assume using the `Y-m-d` format is the way to go?

Comment: Just compare `strtotime(...) <= time()`, much more straight forward.